# How to get data from associated table in sequelize

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

could not find a way to get subqueries to work with sequelize so I used raw querying. I am trying to figure out how to get data from associated tables when I do a raw query. This is what I have tried, but it only returns the data from the primary table and nothing from the associated table:

```
const rawQuery = `select * from (
        select distinct on ("patientId") *
        from public."Billings"
        order by "patientId","createdAt" desc) as "recentPatientBilling"
        where balance > 0;`;
      const debtors = await sequelize.query(
        rawQuery,
        {
          model: Billing,
          mapToModel: true,
          nest: true,
          raw: true,
          include: [{
            model: Patient, attributes: ['id']
          }]
        }
      );
```

The association is:

```
Billing.associate = function(models) {
    Billing.belongsTo(models.User, {
      foreignKey: 'employeeId',
      as: 'employee'
    });
    Billing.belongsTo(models.Patient, {
      foreignKey: 'patientId',
      as: 'patient'
    });
  };
```

Any ideas on how I can get this working? (edited)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try putting {as:'patient'} in the include statement?

```
 include: [{
        model: Patient, 
        as:'patient',
      attributes: ['id']
      }]
```